# Segmentation fault -- How!

Tags: c++

```
int Sequence::scoreDegeneracy()
{
    cout << "Score Degeneracy" << name << seqLen << endl;
    int f = 0;
    if (degenComputed == false)
    {
        char _2foldTest = '*';
        char _4foldTest = '*'; 
        int aaseqLen = seqLen/3;
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < aaseqLen; i++)

        {
            _4foldTest = is4FoldDegenerateSite(i);
            _2foldTest = is2FoldDegenerateSite(i,_4foldTest);
            degScores.totalCodons++
                if (_2foldTest != '*')
            {
                degScores.totalCodons_2fold++;
                if (_2foldTest == 'A')
                {
                    degScores.total_2fold_A++;
                }
                            else if (_2foldTest == 'T')
                {
                    degScores.total_2fold_T++;
                }
                            else if (_2foldTest == 'G')
                {
                    degScores.total_2fold_G++;
                }
                             else
                {
                    degScores.total_2fold_C++;   
                }  
            }else if (_4foldTest != '*')
            {
                degScores.totalCodons_4fold++;
                if (_4foldTest == 'A')
                {
                    degScores.total_4fold_A++;
                }
                            else if (_4foldTest == 'T')
                {
                    degScores.total_4fold_T++;
                }
                            else if (_4foldTest == 'C')
                {
                    degScores.total_4fold_C++;
                }
                            else
                {
                    degScores.total_4fold_G++;
                }
            }
            cout << "Crashes right here when i = 0." << endl;        
        } 
    }
    degenComputed = true;
    return 1;
}
```

Driving me nuts! SegFault happens right at end of first iteration of for loop. Behaves EXACTLY like it supposed to, first test returns right results.. The segmentation fault happens before i is even incremented....

What am I missing??

...

```
char Sequence::is4FoldDegenerateSite(int codonIndex){
 char aminoAcid = aaSeq[codonIndex];
 //cout << "Amino acid of codon number " << codonIndex << " is: " << aminoAcid << endl;
 int loc = readingFrame + (codonIndex * 3) + 2;  
 int locR = loc - 2;
 switch (aminoAcid){
  case 'A':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'T':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'V':  
   return seq[loc];      
  case 'G':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'P':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'S'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (seq[locR] == 'T'){ 
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';
   }    
  case 'R'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (seq[locR] == 'C'){
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';
   }
  case 'L'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (seq[locR] == 'C'){ 
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';   
   }   
 }  
 return '*';
}
char Sequence::is2FoldDegenerateSite(int codonIndex, char _4FoldResults){
 char aminoAcid = aaSeq[codonIndex];
 int loc = readingFrame + (codonIndex * 3) + 2;
 //char doubleDegeneracyTest = is4FoldDegenerateSite(codonIndex);
 //bool doubleDegeneracy = false;
 //if (doubleDegeneracyTest != '*') doubleDegeneracy = true;  
 switch (aminoAcid){
  case 'N':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'D':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'C':  
   return seq[loc];      
  case 'Q':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'E':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'H':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'K':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'F':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'Y':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'X':
   return seq[loc];
  case 'S'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (_4FoldResults == '*'){ 
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';
   }    
  case 'R'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (_4FoldResults == '*'){
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';
   }
  case 'L'://Can also be 2 fold degenerate
   if (_4FoldResults == '*'){ 
    return seq[loc];
   }else{ 
    return '*';   
   }   
 }  
 return '*';
}
```

Valgrind Results:

```
**17043** new/new[] failed and should throw an exception, but Valgrind
==17043==    at 0x4024E35: VALGRIND_PRINTF_BACKTRACE (valgrind.h:3720)
==17043==    by 0x40253C2: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D70A7: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7EDC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D83AF: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804BA7F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:2168)
==17043==    by 0x804ACDF: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:108)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
**17043**    cannot throw exceptions and so is aborting instead.  Sorry.
==17043==    at 0x4024E35: VALGRIND_PRINTF_BACKTRACE (valgrind.h:3720)
==17043==    by 0x40253D0: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D70A7: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7EDC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D83AF: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804BA7F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:2168)
==17043==    by 0x804ACDF: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:108)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
Loading sequence..==17043== 
==17043== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17043==     in use at exit: 2,749,679 bytes in 10 blocks
==17043==   total heap usage: 39,043 allocs, 39,032 frees, 80,022,672,644 bytes allocated
==17043== 
==17043== 27 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7340: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7525: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804969E: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7340: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7525: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x80496C3: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 83 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D70A7: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7EDC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D814A: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40B3F3E: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40C9799: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804ACB5: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:106)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D70A7: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7EDC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D814A: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40B3F3E: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40C9799: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804AC07: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:101)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7340: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D75D1: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D33C5: std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_istringstream(std::string const&, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804AC42: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:103)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 8,192 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025024: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:258)
==17043==    by 0x40A2592: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_allocate_internal_buffer() (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40A65B1: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40A7EAF: std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804ABBF: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:97)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 8,192 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025024: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:258)
==17043==    by 0x40A2592: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_allocate_internal_buffer() (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40A65B1: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40A7EAF: std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804AC9D: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:105)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== 2,732,253 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 10
==17043==    at 0x4025390: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
==17043==    by 0x40D6435: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D70A7: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D7EDC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x40D83AF: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==17043==    by 0x804BA7F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:2168)
==17043==    by 0x804ACDF: GenomeSeq::setup() (GenomeSeq.C:108)
==17043==    by 0x804A4FE: GenomeSeq::GenomeSeq(std::string, std::string) (GenomeSeq.C:52)
==17043==    by 0x80496DF: main (Main2.C:143)
==17043== 
==17043== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17043==    definitely lost: 2,748,975 bytes in 8 blocks
==17043==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17043==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17043==    still reachable: 704 bytes in 2 blocks
==17043==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17043== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==17043== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==17043== 
==17043== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17043== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 8)
```

Sequence.h:

```
#ifndef SEQUENCE_H
#define SEQUENCE_H
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
class GeneSeqs;
class Sequence{
    public:
        Sequence();
        Sequence(char * seqStart,char * aaSeqStart, int length);//Constructor
        ~Sequence();//Destructor -- for the transprof
        //void setup();//Setups up variables.
        char &operator[](int);
        char * getSeq(){return seq;}//returns the address of sequence
        string getAASeq(){return aaSeq;}//returns address of aaSeq
        int getLength(){return seqLen;}
        bool isPositive(){return positiveStrand;}
        /**
         * Setters
         */ 
        void setRevC(char * sequ){revC = sequ;}
        void setSeq(char * sequ){
            seq = sequ;
        }
        void setAASeq(char * a){aaSeq = a;}
        void setLength(int len){seqLen = len;}
        void setAALength(int len){aaSeqLen = len;}
        void setPositivity(bool trufal){
            positiveStrand = trufal;
            if (trufal == false){
                buildRevC();
            }
        }
        //
        int getTCount(){return count.T;}
        int getACount(){return count.A;}
        int getCCount(){return count.C;}
        int getGCount(){return count.G;}
        //void setAASeq(int * a){aaSeq = a;}
        string get_aaSeq(){return aaSeq;}
        bool get_aaSeqExhists(){return aaSeqTranslated;}
        int get_aaSeqLen(){return aaSeqLen;}
        void print();
        void printAA();
        char getAA(int i){return aaSeq[i];}
        int getAALoc(char aa){return AAchar2num(aa);}
        float getMIMScore(){return MIMScore;}
        void setMIM(float MIM){MIMScore = MIM;}
        void translateToAA(int code);
        void computeCrudeCompositions();
        int scoreDegeneracy();
        void degeneracyReport();
        void setName(string n){name = n;}
        float distanceMeasure(Sequence * target);
        bool degeneracyIsScored(){return degenComputed;}
        float distanceMeasure(GeneSeqs * target);
        float distanceMeasureA(GeneSeqs * target, int point, float runningSum);
        int getDegenData(int code);
        void setStartConstant(int i){start = i;}
        void printInfo();
    private:
        struct nucleotideCounts{
            int T;
            int C;
            int A;
            int G;      
        }count;
        struct degeneracyScores{
            int totalCodons;
            int totalCodons_4fold;
            int totalCodons_2fold;
            int total_4fold_A;
            int total_4fold_T;
            int total_4fold_C;
            int total_4fold_G;
            int total_2fold_A;
            int total_2fold_T;
            int total_2fold_G;
            int total_2fold_C;          
        }degScores;
        string name;
        char is4FoldDegenerateSite(int codonIndex);
        char is2FoldDegenerateSite(int codonIndex, char _4FoldResults);
        bool degenComputed;
        float MIMScore;
        void buildRevC();
        string revC;
        char nucleoRevC(char c);
        char * seq;
        int readingFrame;//zero till used...
        int aaSeqLen;
        bool aaSeqTranslated;
        int start;
        int seqLen; //Number of nucleotides in sequence
        bool positiveStrand; //Positive strand = true, negative = false;
        //bool hasY;
        //Genetic sequence in numerical Amino Acide representation;
        string aaSeq;
        void geneSegments2AASeq();
        void computeAATransProf();
        int AAchar2num(char x);
        char AAnum2char(int x);
        char codon2AA(int codonIndex);
        char codon2AA(char * codon);
        char codon2AA(int * codon);
        int Int(string num);    
        int Int(char num);
        char num2nucleo(int a);
        void codonSeq2AASeq();
        int char2nucleo2(char a);
        string String(int num);     
};
#endif
```

Comment: Can you please use larger indentation? This is hard to read.

Comment: Some notes about your code:  1.  Don't use underscores as the first characters in an identifier.  2.  Try using a `switch` statement instead of the `if-else if-else` ladder.

Comment: That code is the sort of thing to give me heartburn. It'd be easier if you reduced the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) a bit.

Comment: Please post the header class `Sequence` as there are a number of undefined variables.

Comment: Your code is non-compilable - missing a semicolon after `degScores.totalCodons++`. How do people manage to post such a large amount of non-compilable code? Did you type it up by hand? Copy-pasted code would surely be compilable.

Comment: Every C/C++ coder in history has uttered "Seg fault? how?!". :-)

Comment: LoL I could imagine  glowcoder...

AndreyT your a troll. Obviously it was a copy paste discrepancy.

Thomas Matthews, C Ross - I agree the code can use cleanup, but along the development it was always more important to get timely results so sometimes these methods get added last minute. I will clean up later.

Comment: So, as the valgrind results show, something is going wrong inside the `GenomeSeq::setup()` method, which you haven't posted the code for. Are you perhaps trying to allocate an absurdly large amount of memory in there?

Comment: Perhaps. I am loading a 2.7MB file that is ~2.8 million characters long. I am loading that into one main string which serves as the basis of the GenomeSeq object... never gave me trouble so I dont see how it would now. Especially since this degeneracyScore has nothing to do with GenomeSeq.

Comment: @Greg D: How can I possible be leaking that string? How does one go about writing code that causes his string object to cause memory faults?

Comment: @yShalabi:  did you read the Valgrind log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> total heap usage: 39,043 allocs, 39,032 frees, 80,022,672,644 bytes allocated
> ```

80GB?? I think you have a memory leak somewhere...

I'd vote for the way you're handling "seq" as a char*, vs. using std:string in other places. Looks like an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Are you on a unix or linux box?  If so, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a great tool for solving these kinds of problems.

Comment: valgrind results added to main post.

Answer (score 4):

Either `is4FoldDegenerateSite` or `is2FoldDegenerateSite` is corrupting your stack, then when the program attempts to branch back to the start of the for, the stack is off so you branch to bad memory.

Look at those two functions and make sure they are cleaning up their memory correctly. Do you have code from either of those functions that you could post?

EDIT:
You overload the `[]` operator. Maybe that is a good place to look? The code is pretty damn complex to have strangers debug remotely.

Comment: Sorry I just ran out of... well everything. This segmentation fault has had me stopped for 3 days now.

Answer (score 1):

Start removing things piece by piece (block comments are helpful) to figure out what affects your crash.  Correctness is irrelevant in this troubleshooting technique.  If removing anything fixes it, you're probably looking at something systemic.

The sad fact is that your problem isn't local to the crashsite, so sending the bits and pieces around the crash site isn't sufficient to for us to discover your bug.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt about the way you are handling seq variable in Sequence class. 
For now, I would suggest you to add

```
bool Sequence::isValid (int loc){
  if ((seq != NULL) && (loc < strlen(seq))) { return true; } // optimize it later
  else { return false; }
}
```

and update is4FoldDegenerateSite() && is2FoldDegenerateSite() with following,

```
int loc = readingFrame + (codonIndex * 3) + 2;  
int locR = loc - 2;

if (isValid(loc) == false) return '*';
// also validate locR before using it.
```

In my opinion you should also add some exception handling; update setSeq(char * sequ) & setLength(int len) to throw exceptions in case of invalid input.

hth

Comment: Thanks for a very good suggestion. I decided to just do away with the whole one genome with subsequences pointing to their respective starts and just do one genome and every subsequence has its own sequence stored as a string. More expensive but I will optimize later. As of right now as long as I have results by tom I really dont care.

but I will definitely roll back and try to see if some part of the computation was operating out of bounds and causing all this.